# Referring to the address of a collection element via iterators

Tags: c++

How can I refer to the address of an element in a vector using iterators.

```
vector<Record>::const_iterator iter = collectionVector.begin();
while(iter != collectionVector.end())
{

//How can I refer to the address of a Record here
function(...); //accepts &Record type

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `&(*iter)` to get the address. Here is a sample code:

```
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter = a.begin();
    int *p = &(*iter) ;
    *p =10;
```

Comment: Getting error|error: invalid conversion from ‘const Record*’ to ‘Record*’|

Comment: @Simi Paul: That is because you are using `const_iterator` as the type of `iter`. You need to either change the type of `iter` to `iterator` or change the signature of `function` to use `const Record*` instead of `Record*`